# How to fix my filtering for products in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***The task is to create a Fiter.jsx component that will filter Products.jsx (you can see it in the repository)***

**I have React Components :**

***Main.jsx***

```
import React from "react";
import { Products } from "../Products";
import { Filter } from "../Filter";
import { Product } from "../Product";

class Main extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [],
    filteredProducts: [],
    status: "all",
  };

  onFilterStatusChange = (status) => {
    this.setState({ status });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("./products.json")
      .then((responce) => responce.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ products: Object.values(data) }));
  }

  filterProducts() {
    this.setState(({ status }) => ({
      filteredProducts:
        status === "all"
          ? this.state.products
          : this.state.products.filter((n) => n.prod_status.includes(status)),
    }));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.status !== prevState.status) {
      this.filterProducts();
    }
  }

  render() {
    // const { products } = this.state;

    return (
      <main className="container content">
        <Filter
          title="Status:"
          values={["all", "recommended", "saleout", "bestseller", "new"]}
          value={this.state.status}
          onChange={this.onFilterStatusChange}
        />
        <Products products={this.state.filteredProducts} />
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export { Main };
```

***Filter.jsx***

```
const Filter = ({ title, values, value, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{title}</h3>
    {values.map((n) => (
      <label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          onChange={() => onChange(n)}
          checked={value === n}
        />
        {n}
      </label>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export { Filter };
```

***At this stage, the console displays an error, and the site shows the following:***

[image]

[image]

## **Question - help fix this...**

[Repo](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Sky-shop-Task-React-) with all files

***Before trying to create a filter, the site looked like this :***

[image]

Comment: Seems like one of the items in your `products` array doesn't have a `prod_status`.  Can you console.log those out and double check?

Comment: Can you please share your products.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey as others have pointed that some `products` do not have a `prod_status` so change `n.prod_status.includes(status)` to `n.prod_status?.includes(status)` in `filterProducts`, which is in the `Main` component.

One more thing is that on the initial render it shows **Nothing found** but the `status` is set to `all`. It should show all the products available. To fix this
change the condition
`this.state.status !== prevState.status` in `component.didUpdate`
to
`this.state.status !== prevState.status || this.state.products !== prevState.products`.

Since on first render `status` value will not change ie. `all` but product changes from [] to [item...]. So check whether the products have changed or not and then run the `filterProducts` function.

Lastly, As the file `products.json`  is in the public directory so in `fetch` call you should write the file path starting with a `/`.

Comment: Can you explain me (or send material) about "?", because i don't understand why we need to put it in `n.prod_status?.includes(status)` ( but of course, it's working)

Comment: That is called `Optional chaining`.You can read about it from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining. As its name suggests it makes chaining optional.  For instance here `n.prod_status?.includes(status)`, if `n.prod_status` is undefined for some products, an error will be thrown. That is because we can't do `undefined.includes(status)` as  `undefined` doesn't have the `includes` method defined. `?` prevents chaining. If a property is accessed from an object, which is `null` or `undefined`,  then it returns `undefined`.